# Extracting text based on partial ID

Tags: text-processing

I have a fastq file. Each entry in the file has four lines as following

```
@0e249669-03e7-47e0-9bc2-a9bcaa35e198 runid=435beb2485d20d8e06f3b38ed907a08f8147fa77 read=100 ch=83 start_time=2018-10-27T12:20:46Z
ACGTATGCCCCGTTCAGTTGCACGTATTGCTATTAGTCACCATTACTTCTTCCTATTTGATGTGAAACCAAGGCAGAGATACTTTTCTGGGTGGTATTTGGGAGGTGGTGAGGCGATTCAAATCCAGGTCTCTCTGGGGACCTTGTTCTTAACCCCTGTACCCCCAGCCATCTGATATAATACTTTT
+
%)"+"""&(,,(,42(--/#)&()1,//./2,7,++8735/-+*#%*3-06,*($(&""#&$)(%.,,2/,#("#$##$')#$-13/*)(-/+(.-*'.+*0)&)&&
```

Lines do not have any empty line.

This is only one entry such that I have thousands of entries in the text file.

I have another file as following

```
@0e249669-03e7-47e0-9bc2-a9bcaa35e198
@e5cbeff3-5c28-46e4-a991-3dfded8505de
```

How do I extract all the four lines of each record using the list of these unique IDs?

Output should be following

```
@0e249669-03e7-47e0-9bc2-a9bcaa35e198 runid=435beb2485d20d8e06f3b38ed907a08f8147fa77 read=100 ch=83 start_time=2018-10-27T12:20:46Z
ACGTATGCCCCGTTCAGTTGCACGTATTGCTATTAGTCACCATTACTTCTTCCTATTTGATGTGAAACCAAGGCAGAGATACTTTTCTGGGTGGTATTTGGGAGGTGGTGAGGCGATTCAAATCCAGGTCTCTCTGGGGACCTTGTTCTTAACCCCTGTACCCCCAGCCATCTGATATAATACTTTT
+
%)"+"""&(,,(,42(--/#)&()1,//./2,7,++8735/-+*#%3-06,($(&""#&$)(%.,,2/,#("#$##$')#$-13/)(-/+(.-'.+*0)&)&&
```

Comment: Are the first four lines you show always in a block of four related records? So the "other list" is in a separate file, and you want to grab 4 records for each line in your other list, and ignore any other groups of four?

Comment: yes. based on the partial ID from another list (that is another file), I want to grab all the four lines

Comment: Please don't split up your example text. Show them exactly as is.

Comment: I have changed the example text. both the file entry starts with @

Comment: I'm guilty of splitting up the example text.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following command line will do the job. The data are in the file `fast-file` and the data-group names are in the file 'list'.

```
while read line;do name=${line%% *}; grep -A3 "$name" fast-file ;done < list
```

or if you want to remove `</br>` tokens,

```
while read line;do name=${line%% *}; grep -A3 "$name" fast-file ;done < list | sed 's%</br>%%'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but somehow it does not work. I would like all the four lines based on the match

Comment: @Trupti, Maybe the files are not linux files, but in some other format, for example DOS files or maybe there is some special formatting, that is not possible to see from your question. It would help, if you can upload real files somewhere, for example at https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @Trupti, I modified the pattern for grep slightly (now there is an `@` in the beginning of each line in the 'name file'. Please try again with the modified command line (and please upload a real 'fast file')).

Comment: you were right. the files were not linux. I used the mac file. when I run the same one liner on linux it works. Thank you very much.